# Yii2 request parameter from url

Tags: yii, yii2

In YII I could request a parameter from url and populate a form field called `companyAdd_id` with the following code, trying to do the same in YII2 but getting errors, looking for advice on how to do the same in YII2. thanks

```
<?php echo $companyAdd_id = Yii::app()->request->getParam('companyAdd_id'); ?>

<?php echo $form->hiddenField($model, 'companyAdd_id', array(
        'type'  => 'text',
        'value' => $companyAdd_id
)); ?>

<?php echo $form->error($model, 'companyAdd_id'); ?>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can use the following code in Yii2:

```
     Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('companyAdd_id')
```

Answer (score 22):

`<?= Yii::$app->request->get('companyAdd_id') ?>`

Answer (score 1):

```
 Yii::$app->getRequest()->getQueryParam('companyAdd_id')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use like this one.

```
Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('companyAdd_id');
```

Comment: Isn't this just the same as one of the other answers?

Comment: No It's different. You might be check it with previous answers..!! :)